# running a long cron job - should I break it into smaller processes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a PHP script that accesses the Amazon API at 11:00pm each night. The process takes a few hours. Will this lock up my server (haven't deployed it yet)? Is it best to run this in small batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process takes a few hours.

You probably want to ensure the *max_execution_time* is not defined in the php.ini or set sufficiently high and you might want to execute the script directly and not by a HTTP request to a web server.

> Will this lock up my server (haven't deployed it yet)?

Possibly, but that completely depends on what the script is intended to do (and actually does). Long running scripts/programs are generally not a problem.

> Is it best to run this in small batches?

It depends, for instance what happens when a batch fails to complete, is it safe to run again, will it pick up where it was left, does a subsequent batch have dependancies on earlier batches, can multiple batches run parallel (and is it beneficial to do so) to name a few concerns